# How to Join model in Mongodb(Mongoose) and express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have 3 models 'User' , 'Doctor', 'Appointment', I want to let the user make an appointment then when he get his appointment I want to return the doctor name, also when the doctor get the appointment I want t return the user Name.

User Model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

},

password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

},
 })

const User = mongoose.model('User', User);

 module.exports = { User };
```

Doctor Model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Doctor = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

},

password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,

 },

})

const Doctor = mongoose.model('Doctor', Doctor);

module.exports = { Doctor };
```

Appointment Model :

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const Appointment = mongoose.Schema({
date: {
    type: Date,

},
time: {
    type: Date
},

_userID: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},

_doctorID: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Doctor'
}
})

 const Appoitment = mongoose.model('Appoitment', Appointment);

    module.exports = { Appoitment };
```

Make and Get Appointment :

```
   const express = require('express');
   const { Appointment } = require('../DataBase/Models/appointment.model');
   const router = express.Router();



  router.get("/appointment/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const appointment = await Appointment.find({
        user: req.params.id,
    }).populate({
        path: "doctor",
        model: "Doctor",
    });
    res.send({
        status: 200,
        message: "SuccessFull",
        Appointments: appointment,
    });
} catch (error) {
    res.send({
        status: 400,
        message: `Error: ${error}`,
    });
}
});

 router.post("/appointment", async (req, res) => {

try {
    const makeAppointment = new Appointment(req.body);
    const result = await makeAppointment.save();
    res.send({
        status: 200,
        message: "SuccessFull",
        Appointment: result,
    });
} catch (error) {
    res.send({
        status: 404,
        message: `Error : ${error}`,
    });
}
 });
```

My Question is How I can return the Appointment with the doctor Name the same with the User Name  ??

Comment: What isn't working? You're on the right path, you need to use `populate`, but according to [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population), you only need to give him the key you want to populate. You can also populate multiple fields: `.populate('doctor', 'user');`

Comment: Do you also want to populate any field when you are creating a new appointment?

Comment: I just want to populate the user name and the doctor name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `.populate` method, the path param is the name of the attribute in the model that you're trying to retrieve, so instead of `path: 'doctor'`, you should be using `'_doctorID'` because you used this as the attribute name in the Appointment Model.
The same works for your query in the `.find`, you're querying the '`user'` attribute, but you have `_userID` in your appointment model.

So, you have to 2 options:

1. Change `_userID` and `_doctorID` to `user` and `doctor`, this way should be better;
2. Or change `user` and `doctor` in your controller to `_userID` and `_doctorID`;

If you follow the first option, your code now should be something like:

Appointment Model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
       
const Appointment = mongoose.Schema({
    date: {
        type: Date,
    },
    time: {
        type: Date
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    doctor: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Doctor'
    }
})
        
const Appoitment = mongoose.model('Appoitment', Appointment);
module.exports = { Appoitment };
```

Appointment Controller:

```js
router.get("/appointment/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const appointment = await Appointment.find({
            user: req.params.id,
        })
            .populate({
                path: "doctor",
                select: "_id name",
            });
        res.send({
            status: 200,
            message: "SuccessFull",
            Appointments: appointment,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.send({
            status: 400,
            message: `Error: ${error}`,
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select specific column .
it will look like  `.populate('author', 'name'). // only return the Author name`